# Combining multiple kernel sizes in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is there a way to combine (say max or average) the output from a convolution layer that uses multiple kernel sizes? For example, if I use a kernel sizes of (2*2), (3*2), (2*3) instead of using just 1 kernel of size(2*3) and in the next layer take an average or max of output of all these values?

Comment: I think your answer is in your question. You can additionally just merge along the channels dimension. This is what SqueezeNet does in the Fire Module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Convolutional filters operate on all feature maps they receive as input
- The output of each convolutional filter is a single feature map.
- The output dimension is the same, when you apply padding. Then the size of the convolutional filter does not matter.

Then, filters can be "joined" in several ways:

- [Concatenation](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) of the output feature maps. For sure the most common one.
- [Summation](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#add) is used in Resnets
- [Others](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) like multiplication. But I think one could say they all use concatenation and another operation after it.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want a general introduction into CNNs, I can recommend [chapter 2 of my masters thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf#page=11)

Comment: Does the choice of padding make a difference while concatenation? For eg: If I combine layers with filter sizes 1*1, 3*3, 5*5 with padding same or valid does it affect accuracy differently? P.S. I will need to manage the output sizes for valid padding though.

Comment: If the feature maps don't have the same shape, you can't concatenate them. If you don't have padding=same and you have different filter sizes, the feature map will have different sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Kernel sizes are not crucial here, what matters is what is the output size from each convolution operation. If only you adjust padding, stride etc. to make sure that each of your conv-operations output the same shape (up to batch and channels dimensions) you can just concatenate over channel, and either aggregate (sum, average) or just continue with bigger amount of channels.

This kind of approach was used for a long time, for example in old, well known inception network
[image]